# Increase the letters per line in DOS Output

Tags: windows-7, command-line, printing, dot-matrix-printer

I am printing no of lines in DOS(CMD Prompt In Windows 7) using Batch file into DOT MATRIX Printer. Its A5 Paper. The problem is I cant able to add more than 53 characters per line for A5 print. How to increase the characters per line for this A5 size.

Comment: Is it actually MS-DOS? Or the Windows CMD prompt?

Comment: its CMD Prompt in Windows 7

Comment: What's the make and model of the printer?

Comment: TVS MSP 250 Star Dot Matrix Printer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This printer (TVS MSP 250 Star) supports ESC/P (this is an Epson standard) and IBM Proprinter emulation. This means you can send a small file before your actual file which switches the printer to condensed mode.

For the ESC/P emulation you can do the following:

Make a `small.txt` file:

```
<#27><#15>
```

This is not a literal file. The file should be just 2 character (#27 and #15). You'll need an editor who can create an "Escape" (#27) and "Condensed" (#15) character (e.g. Hex-editor). If you don't have one see below how to make the file.

Next you can print your file like this:

```
copy small.txt+ACTUAL_FILE.TXT LPT1
exit
```

---

If you don't have a Hex-editor you can do the following:

Make a textfile with the following (call it `small.vbs`):

```
Wscript.Stdout.Write Chr(27)+Chr(15)
```

Then execute the following on a command prompt:

```
cscript /nologo small.vbs > small.txt
```

This will result in a `small.txt` file which you can use with the copy command.

Edit: It is recommended to try `#15` only first. If that does not work try `#27#15`.

To write `#15` in C# you could use `(char)15` or `\x0F`.

From the [ESC/P manual](http://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf):
[image]
and

[image]

**Edit**:

To summarize (excluding the borders/margins, so it could be less with margins):

- 10cpi ≈ 58 characters = Esc P (`#27P`)
- 12cpi ≈ 70 characters = Esc M (`#27M`)
- 15cpi ≈ 87 characters = Esc g (`#27g`)
- 10cpi condensed ≈ 100 characters = Esc P SI (`#27P#15`)
- 12cpi condensed ≈ 116 characters = Esc M SI (`#27M#15`)
- 15cpi condensed ≈ (not available)

So the smallest would be `#27M#15`. (116 characters)

If you don't need the file to be opened in a normal editor you can include these codes in your file. You can then also add goodies like bold, italic etc. To set a word in bold you could do the following:

`This is a #27Ebold#27F word.`

`#27E` sets bold and `#27F` cancels it again. You could also switch back to 10cpi and combine it with bold.

`#27M#15This is a #18#27P#27Ebold#27F#27M#15 word.`

`#27M#15` to set it to 12cpi condensed. `#18` to cancel condensed. `#27P` to set 10cpi and after the word `#27M#15` to set it to 12cpi condensed again.

You could also use the "Double font width/height":

`#27M#15This is a #27W#1#27w#1big#27W#0#27w#0 word.`

`#27W#1` Double font width and `#27w#1` Double font height and `#0` to cancel them again.

You see that you can combine all of these codes to do anything. There is also a "Master Select" (page 125 of the manual). If you switch a lot between fonts you can use that to switch cpi, bold, condensed, italic etc in one command. (`#27!`+n where n is the type)

Comment: i am writing into text file using c#. Is it possible to write in sample.vbs file using c#.
And its not mentioned how many characters per line i can able to print

Comment: If you're writing the text-file yourself you could also just add #27#15 before the file itself (no need for the `small.txt`). BTW it is recommended to just try #15 only first. If the #15 before the file does not work try #27#15. You can use `(char)15` or `\x0F` in C#.

Comment: How many characters it will print per line?

Comment: I added a screenshot from the manual. when 12Cpi is selected condensed will be 20cpi. To select 12cpi you can also do `#27M` (or `char(27)` + `M`)

Comment: Added a link to the [ESC/P manual](http://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf) from Epson. You can find more handy codes like draft, proportional printing etc.

Comment: 14,85cm / 2,54 (cm/inch) = 5,84 * 20 character = 116 characters max per line. If this is too small you could also select 15cpi (`Esc g`). This would be 87 characters per line. (or 70 if you choose 12cpi `Esc M`)

Comment: thanks for your big support. Its really very useful i will check it with printer after that i will mark it answer.... and thank you very much for your support.

Comment: BTW if you also need the files to be accessible via an editor it is best to not include the `#15` in the file and write the `small.txt` yourself in C# because some editors can't handle character below #32. Otherwise just include then in front of your original file.

Comment: its worked.thank you very much.I set `Esc g` Its Increased to 70+.Is it possible to increase more... and how to increase size of font for specific word...

Comment: Yes, you can do `#27P#15` for 100 characters and `#27M#15` for 116 characters. I added some info to my answer on how to change a word during printing (bigger, bold etc). With this info you could almost write a "html to printer" in C#. Your base file could be with <b> etc and while reading it you could print it with these codes. (There are probably already some of these utilities :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find the printer language the printer is using.  Then, look up and send the condensed print command before the job.  Many dot matrix type devices used an escape code sequence so you'd send the esc character sometimes seen as 027 hex and then a sequence of characters.  This sequence tells the printer to change fonts, line spacing, font size...  Note that it is particular to the printer.  There wasn't a truly universal language.